# What are the Implications of different alias syntax and its effect on character length output of that alias row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Microsoft SQL server manager studio
(This snippet was to search for blank spaces in certain columns)

I have informed that the usage of:

```sql
sqlMPDD = REPLACE(MP.Scale, ' ', '?'))
```

Can 'sometimes', in the results row for MPDD show the "Maximum number of characters displayed in each column" which is set to 256 characters as standard despite that row only having 10 characters; it shows the 10 characters and a lot of blank space.
(Tools>Options>Query Results>SQL SERVER>RESULTS TO TEXT>Max No. of char disp in each col)

Whereas `'MPDD' = REPLACE(MP.Scale, ' ', '?'))`
would display as many spaces as there are characters in the results row

I understand you can fix this by:

```sql
MPDD = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), REPLACE(MP.Scale, ' ', '?'))
```

but am also told by a senior dev that too many functions with a system that runs thousands if not hundreds of thousands of lines of code can be slowed down by too many functions.

Any insight into this subject and I would be most grateful as I cannot find anything on this particular distinction.

Comment: I really don't follow what you are asking here. `REPLACE(MP.Scale, ' ', '?'))` could never result in a string based value *longer* than the value if `MP.Scale` as you are replacing a single character with another single character (a whitespace (`' '`) with a question mark (`'?'`)). As for using multiple function, this can, but you needs to be using *a lot* (like 100's of them in a single expression). Wrapping a `REPLACE` inside a `CONVERT`  isn't going to have much of a difference in performance (`REPLACE` is going to be more expensive).

Comment: What is the type of `MP.Scale`? A `CHAR` of a particular size will always be padded to a fixed length, whereas, if you don't like spaces, `LTRIM`/`RTRIM`/`TRIM` would get rid of them. It's unclear what replacing them with question marks is supposed to accomplish. If you want to search for values containing trailing spaces, use something like `WHERE value LIKE '% '`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It seems you have multiple questions - something not well suited to this site and a cause for closing. I suggest you focus on one. The 256 character limit is simply a convenience option in SSMS - not certain why you are asking a question about that while posting some SQL. If you want to see more characters or fewer characters personally then set the option as you desire. It does not affect the query itself just what you see as a resultset.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? Replacing spaces with question marks feels like an odd thing to do on its face. Additionally, how SSMS displays certain things shouldn't be a driving factor in design decisions.

Comment: Sorry about my poorly formed question, it lacks clarity and context.

I was trying (failing) to ask whether an error (255 spaces in column associated query result) can occur from using different syntax for naming with the ALIAS function.
I was told this can happen in rare circumstances but was unsure so I asked the question.
It appears this bug may be a rather obscure and undocumented bug.


I also was wondering about the effect of functions in slowing down database activity.

Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I have read your question 4 times and from what I understand what you are asking is: "how to reduce column width of a specific column in returned results when using Results to Text option in SSMS".

Answer:

YES, `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) ....` is the solution

AND

NO, `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) ....` system function will not impact performance in a practical way.

Another useful feature in SSMS is "[Vertical Block Select Mode](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/06/06/sql-server-vertical-select-mode-feature-sql-server-management-studio/)" which allows you to edit multiple lines of text at once. This is useful for removing unnecesary white space in Result to Text columns.

RE "but am also told by a senior dev that too many functions with a system that runs thousands if not hundreds of thousands of lines of code can be slowed down by too many functions": you senior dev is talking about user defined functions. Yes they can slow things down.